# HELP, URGENT!!! PLEASE RESPOND!

Tags: hadith, practical-islam

I exposed my sins and sometimes foolishly I expose others too if I sincerely repent to Allah. Can i still have my sins concealed on the Day of Judgement. I cannot stop thinking!

Comment: Are you guys 100% sure that my sin be concealed on the Day of Judgement

Comment: "HELP, URGENT!!! PLEASE RESPOND!" is far away from [this](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1837/advice-for-writing-question-titles-on-islam-se) "urgent questions" shouldn't be asked here, as we are neither a fatwa site nor a fast answering service. A sin is never concealed, but sincere repentence can overweight it.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you exposed your sins, Allah will conceal them for you if you sincerely make Tawbah (repentance). Here is a nice infographic that will help you with your Tawbah:
[image]

This shows step by step instructions to making Tawbah. If you sincerely follow these instructions and make Tawbah, Allah will conceal your sins and forgive you.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu alaikum brother, no matter what your sin is no matter how many times  you do that once you go to Allah and repent sincerely Allah will forgive you. Because Allah has said no matter how many times you sin once you come to me and ask for my forgiveness I will forgive you. But only thing here to be aware of is that you are repentance should be genuine . That is you should be feeling guilty about your sins and you should be clear about not repeating those ever again. Allah knows better